# How to call a stored procedure at application start up in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, stored-procedures

I have Written a stored procedure in data.sql, now I want to call this procedure at the application start up.

Comment: You can use an `EventListener` on `ApplicationStartedEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement **CommandLineRunner** interface in you main application class and can override run method as below :-

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    //code for stored procedure call goes here
    }
}
```